# If statement in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, select, syntax-error

I want a column that just displays good or bad based on the condition:

```
select (if (salary>10000) then 'good' else 'bad')as "Grade" from employees;
```

It's giving me

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 14 Column: 19
```

The error is at the '>'. How am I supposed to write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could (should?) use the ANSI-SQL `case` expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN salary > 10000 THEN 'good' ELSE 'bad' END AS "Grade"
FROM   employees;
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
select salary, 
   case
      when salary>10000 then 'good' 
      else 'bad' 
   end 
from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing an ‘end if’ before the closing paren

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
select case when (salary>10000) 
  then 'good' 
  else 'bad' 
end as "Grade" from employees;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

SELECT salary, IF(salary>10000, "good", "bad") as "Grade"
FROM employees;